# got this error while deploying my contract

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, ethereumjs, mocha

please help me what is error in above code...

this is my code.and it is exact same code what my course teaher taught.

compile.js

```
   const path = require('path');
    const fs = require('fs');
   const solc=require('solc');


    const inboxPath= path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts', 'Inbox.sol');
   const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8');
       console.log(solc.compile(source,1));
```

//inbox.sol

```
     pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

     contract Inbox {
      string public message;

function Inbox(string  initialMessage) public{
    message = initialMessage;
}

function setmessage(string  newmessage) public  {
    message= newmessage;


}
```

}

---

inbox.test.js

```
const assert = require('assert');
 const ganache =require('ganache-cli');
  const Web3 =require('web3');  //class
  const web3=new Web3(ganache.provider());
   const {interface, bytecode}=require('../compile');

   let accounts;
     let inbox;

     beforeEach(async()=>{
      // get a list of all accounts
       accounts =  await web3.eth.getAccounts();




       // use one of those accounts to deploy the contract
      inbox= await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
     .deploy({ data: bytecode,arguments:['hi there!']})
       .send({ from:accounts[0],gas:'1000000'});
          });


         describe('Inbox',()=>{
        it('deploys a contract',()=>{
        console.log(inbox);
            });
           });
```

this is error i getting

```
    Inbox
     1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract"


      0 passing (42ms)
     1 failing

     1) "before each" hook for "deploys a contract":
       SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
       at Context.<anonymous> (test/inbox.test.js:18:41)
      at processTicksAndRejections 
     (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

---

Comment: console.log the interface. you need "abi" of it

Comment: not getting that , i'm beginner.I am following a course on udemy. I have wrote the same code what he taught.  please tell me what edit should i made in my code....

Comment: it's a syntax error, if you are following a course on udemy, the fast way to find the problem is to check the difference between yours and the teacher's code.

or pls copy paste the original code and error here, thx.

Comment: I had pasted the original code.please check it.

Comment: Have a look at the JSON file 
This is a syntax error which means there is some kind of spelling mistake.
You might have pressed any button on the keyboard mistakenly.